# Where putting logic to Approval user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, tdd, repository-pattern

In my application got:

**Classes**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
     DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public bool ApproveUser(User usr) //This is correct place?
    {
        usr.IsApproved = true;
        db.Attrach(usr);
        return db.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}
```

### Question

Where putting logic approval user?

In Repository? In own class?

I ask this because today is the repository and am having trouble to test this once approval is the logic of production in the repository in the repository and not fake.

Comment: Are you using the the `SqlMembershipProvider` or your own custom membership system?

Comment: Custom. I customize the class `MembershipProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository is the place to write data access. User approval is *more likely* to be business process, so it better be separated from data access. I would do it this way (*code below is more like of pseudocode, not the full production-ready stuff*)

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    bool Save();
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public bool Save(User user)
    {
        db.Attrach(user);
        return db.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}

public interface IUserService
{
   bool Approve(User user);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
   readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

   public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
   { 
      _userRepository = userRepository;
   }

   public bool Approve(User user)
   {
     user.IsApproved = true;
     return _repository.Save(User user);
   }
}
```

And now, this already is the testable code

Comment: It helped me a lot! Just a question ..
For example: 
When creating a new user, I have to add some roles for it.

`var role = (from r in db.Roles
                  where r.Name == "Couple"
                  select r). SingleOrDefault ();`

`user.Roles.Add (role);`

**Where would this logic?**
That would **just be** for **new users**.

Comment: You should do that in some kind of business layer, in my case - same UserService class would be perfect fit. Adding default role is business process - so it should be done in business layer. Repository should be just responsible for saving supplied user as it is to database.

Comment: so I have to create a new Add method in my service layer, and place the business rule?

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do

Comment: Last question, I promise!

In my application, I always do I use my service layer to handle the data?
I never use my repository directly? Or in more complex cases do I use my service layer?

I ask this because my application will have points at which utlize the service layer (with more complex business rules) and others points most simple where only the repository are necessary.

Comment: You know, I do not think there's absolutely clear answer there - it depends on situation. Generally, if you know that business rules are not and will not get more complex than data access, you could directly use repositories and leave them as they are - no point in creating artificial complexity. But in case you are planning to make business rules more complex for future, you could wrap them inside services, as placeholders. What you shouldn't do is mix data access and business layer logics between each other.